# GCP Startup script windows difference

Tags: windows, google-cloud-platform, startup

I want to use start up script in windows for GCP. In documentation it is provided as sysprep-specialize-script-ps1  First during the initial boot and windows-startup-script-ps1    First during each boot after the initial boot. Does this mean sysprep will only execute while creating the instance and does not invoke after every reboot. and windows-startup-script-ps1 invokes while creating instance and after evert reboot.
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/startup-scripts/windows

Answer (score 0):

The sysprep_specialize-script-ps1 script will only run once, when the instance is initially created. It does not run when the instance is restarted.Using the sysprep_specialize-script-ps1 as the metadata key for the startup script, it will execute during the time-of initial booting of the GCE VM. Using windows-startup-script-ps1 will be executed after each time of initial boot. You can use the scripts as per your use case if you want the script to be executed at initial boot use sysprep_specialize-script-ps1 or any other use case as per the [document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/startup-scripts/windows#metadata-keys) you have shared.